# How to navigate to another Screen which has constructor itself but without passing any data

Tags: flutter, constructor, navigation

I have two screens:

- home_page_screen with listed items (each item has an icon 'favourite' which adds to favourites),
- favourites_screen showing the list with clicked favourites items in home_page_screen. I created the favourite_screen with constructor where I am passing the clicked favourites items. When I add the item to favourites in the home_page_screen, the app navigates me to favourite_screen and showing another favourite item.

My question is: How to simply navigate from my home_page_screen to favourites_screen (for example by clicking the icon placed in the NavigationBottomBar **without passing any data, just to navigate me there?**

Comment: Hello ! Could you provide some code ? If your widget needs to handle optional parameters, the following implementation is the one you need  `FavouritesScreen({List<String> favourites})`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) {
          return favourites_screen();
        },
      ),
    );
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like it does not help. I tried and the problem occured:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FavouriteScreen(dirty): The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length

Any idea?

Comment: can you provid me  example of the code ? to help you more